# Ruby - accessing object inside cycle

Tags: ruby

I'm having a little problem with this Ruby code:

```
class Tap
attr_accessor :c, :v, :n, :tname

def initialize(n, c, v)
    @c = c.to_i
    @v = v.to_f
    @n = n.to_i
    @tname = sprintf("T-%d%02d DS", @n, @c)
end
end

#...

taps = Array.new
File.open("taps.txt").each { |line|     
    n, c, v = line.split("\t") 
    tap = Tap.new(n, c, v)
    taps.push tap
}

besttap = Tap.new(100,100,100) # Here I try to create a global varialble
2.upto(floors) { |f|

    l += cable_loss * floor_height
    out << "some text to output"

    bestuserlevel = 10
    besttap = Tap.new(100,100,100)
    taps.each { |tap|
        l_in_tmp = tap.v + l
        userlevel = l_in_tmp - tap.c
        if userlevel.abs < bestuserlevel.abs
            besttap = tap
            bestuserlevel = userlevel
        end
        puts tap.inspect
    }

    l += besttap.v #WELL, I CANNOT ACCESS besttap here. I get that one created with Tap.new(100,100,100), but I need one chosen by the cycle before (it should be something Tap.new(2, 8,0.5) - i.e - best suitable value from taps array )... 


    out << "some text to output"

}
```

`taps` is an array that consists of Hashes.

For some reason, after choosing the right TAP i can access correct `bestuserlevel` value, but no `besttap` (I suppose to have a certain hash there...)

Can anyone please help me sort this out?

Comment: What is the intent of this code?

Comment: to calculate a simple cable network... Signal levels etc

Comment: If you're unwilling to explain further, I'm unable to help you write code that does it. Your code, frankly, is a mess; you're not following conventions, idioms, or best practices. For example, naming variables obscure things like `l_in_tmp`, creating a hash with `Hash.new` instead of `{}`, and creating temporary variables rather than using native `reduce` or creating multi-line blocks with brackets instead of `do...end`.

Comment: see the new variant please. C and V are tap parematers, these names are a standard.

Comment: C and V may be standard, but I very much doubt "l" and "l_in_tmp" are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works fine when I run it. Though I'm assuming those that "+ l" is a "+ 1" here. Perhaps that is your problem?

Other than that typo, this seems to work correctly, so I'm assuming the problem is somewhere in your taps Hash - If you set a static hash with values as a test, does it still break?

I should add that besttap will obviously be empty in any situation where the besttap.replace is not triggered, so that would be where I would look - maybe your input hash doesn't have any values that trigger the replace?

(In which case bestuserlevel would still have a value)

Comment: no. small letter l is a variable name.. I'll edit a code in a minute. see new changes please

Comment: And this is why you shouldn't right such obtuse code and absurd variable names. But yeah, this works for me - your problem is something somewhere outside the code you've posted.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the logic as such, I wonder if its the data you are using. Try putting in some puts inside the condition block and see if the value is captured correctly.

Comment: Yes, make sure that taps is actually getting correctly assigned - give us the value of taps before entering the loop in this example.

Comment: well, I got it. The problem was related to incorrect input data, so the check was never triggered. Thanks for your time and efforts!